# How to remove mouseover/mouseout event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site with three tabs that I'm trying to dynamically add mouseover/mouseout event depending on which tab is clicked, the problem is that it appears that the mouseover/out events are 'bound' to the tab after they're called.  Is there a way to 'unbind' the event from the tabs?

Here's what my js looks like

```
onTab1Clicked()
{
    $('#tab2').mouseover(function() {
        $('#tab2').addClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab2').mouseout(function() {
        $('#tab2').removeClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab3').mouseover(function() {
        $('#tab3').addClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab3').mouseout(function() {
        $('#tab3').removeClass('outlineBorder');
        });
}

onTab2Clicked()
{
    $('#tab1').mouseover(function() {
        $('#tab1').addClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab1').mouseout(function() {
        $('#tab1').removeClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab3').mouseover(function() {
        $('#tab3').addClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab3').mouseout(function() {
        $('#tab3').removeClass('outlineBorder');
        });
}

onTab3Clicked()
{
    $('#tab2').mouseover(function() {
        $('#tab2').addClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab2').mouseout(function() {
        $('#tab2').removeClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab1').mouseover(function() {
        $('#tab1').addClass('outlineBorder');
        });
    $('#tab1').mouseout(function() {
        $('#tab1').removeClass('outlineBorder');
        });
}
```

This works fine on page load but if I click away from tab1 (page load state) to another tab then back to tab1 the mouseover/out events still fire.

Thanks.

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions (via the check-mark beside the one that helped).  It'll help get answers in the future, and helps the next person searching with the same problem, finding your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your approach overall by making some very simple changes here.  First, give those `#tab1`, `#tab2` and `#tab3` elements a class, e.g. `class="tab"` then you can do this:

```
$(".tab").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active'); //make this tab active
  $(".tab").not(this).removeClass('active'); //make other tabs inactive
});
```

Now when you click any tab, it gets the "active" class, and the others won't have it.  Then you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) with the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to get the hover effect you want, like this:

```
$('.tab:not(.active)').live('mouseover mouseout', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('outlineBorder');
});
```

This selector won't act upon a tab while it's `.active`, so the hover effect only works on the tab that *isn't* selected, like you originally had, but much easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 Massive code reduction, no binding/unbinding, clever use of `.live()`, I'd say you just about covered the bases. :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tab1,#tab2,#tab3').click(function(){
    $(this).unbind('mouseout mouseover');
    // this will unbind mouseout and mouseover  events when click
    // e.g. onTab1Clicked, mouseout and mouseover events will be unbind on tab1
})
```

Comment: You can call `.unbind()` with multiple event as well, e.g. `.unbind('mouseout mouseover')`

Comment: Ahh, I was not sure about that Nick, thanks for clearing it to me.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you nearly had it!

```
$('#tab3').unbind('mouseout');
```